# Icon not displaying properly inside option element

Tags: html, css

Inside the spacing-container div, I'm setting an image to appear to the right-hand side of the options, the image is a line spacer icon. However, when I set this icon it's just a big black mark. I've tried resizing it but not got very far with it. The icons which I'm using in the two other divs are working, which display a drop-down icon.

Further, I was hoping to store the icons locally, but when I set the icons they do not come through when I set the background to find the images locally. My file structure is as follows:

CSS 
--> CssImages 
--> -- down-chevron.png
--> -- line-spacing.png
main.css

and I was importing them in this format in my css file.

```
background: transparent url("CSS/CssImages/down-cheron.png")
```

Unfortunately this didn't seem to work, however, upon inspecting in developer tools the images were being pulled through to the local host.

My HTML is here:

```
 <div class="tool-bar">
    <div class="options-container">
        <select>
            <option value = "times-new-roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value = "arial">Arial</option>
            <option value = "courier-new">Courier New</option>
            <option value = "verdana">Verdana</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="options-container font-container">
        <select>
            <option value = "8">8</option>
            <option value = "10">10</option>
            <option value = "12">12</option>
            <option value = "14">14</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="options-container spacing-container">
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
            <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Css snippet is here:

```
.tool-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #a19f9f;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.options-container {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    border-left: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float:left; display:inline;
}

.font-container {
    width: 5%;
}

.spacing-container{
    width: 6%;
}

.options-container select {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    height: 34px;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat center;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position-x: 215px;
}

.font-container select {
    background-position-x: 20px;
}

.spacing-container select {
    background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1827/1827633.svg") 0 0;
    background-position-x: 0;
}
```

I appreciate your time and your advice with the matter.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon you are using is too big, that's why it is not visible. So, you have to use `background-size` property.

```css
.tool-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #a19f9f;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.options-container {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    border-left: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float:left; display:inline;
}

.font-container {
    width: 10%;
}

.spacing-container{
    width: 10%;
}

.options-container select {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    height: 34px;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat center right;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.font-container select {
    background-position-x: 100%;
}

.spacing-container select {
    background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1827/1827633.svg") no-repeat center;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-bar">
    <div class="options-container">
        <select>
            <option value = "times-new-roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value = "arial">Arial</option>
            <option value = "courier-new">Courier New</option>
            <option value = "verdana">Verdana</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="options-container font-container">
        <select>
            <option value = "8">8</option>
            <option value = "10">10</option>
            <option value = "12">12</option>
            <option value = "14">14</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="options-container spacing-container">
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
            <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: beautiful. Thanks for your help, don't suppose you have an ideas to why using the icons locally wouldn't be working?

Comment: local images should also work. can yo try ``background: transparent url("./CSS/CssImages/down-cheron.png")``